# How to establish bijective between the set of rooted trees and natural numbers, using Godel numbering?

Tags: trees

Consider the structure of a rooted tree independent of its underlying set, (i.e. in the sense of trees as combinatorial species). I know a number of ways which we can encode any such tree in natural numbers, but all of them fail to be a bijective, i.e. Some numbers can not be decoded into any sensible tree structure. I would be very pleased to see such concrete correspondence. Thank you.

Comment: If you can encode each structure as a natural number, and there are infinitely many different structures you can collapse the range of the encoding to have a bijection with $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Y. Abe, [Tree representation of positive integers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0893-9659%2894%2990053-1), Applied Mathematics Letters
Volume 7, Issue 1, January 1994, Page 57:

> *Abstract.* We define a natural one-to-one correspondence between the set of positive integers and the set of equivalence classes of isomorphic rooted trees. By this correspondence, one can translate number-theoric concepts or quantities of a positive integer into graph-theoretic ones of a rooted tree. For example, a positive integer is prime if and only if the corresponding rooted tree is planted, that is, the valency of the root is equal to $1$.

Comment: Note that this result was first discovered by Matula (1968): “A natural rooted tree enumeration by prime factorization”.

Answer (score 3):

See also [A new bijection between natural numbers and rooted trees (Cappello)](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~cappello/papers/bijections/p.pdf).

Comment: Repeating my comment above: this result was first discovered by Matula (1968): “A natural rooted tree enumeration by prime factorization”, predating Cappello by 20 years.